# What algorithm could generate this hash?

Tags: encryption, hash

I need to know how to generate this kind of hash. What dows it look like? What could be algorithm name that generated it?

```
3MJVKXEPzins+VZjNUq1Xw==
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That value is [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded. After decoding, it's exactly 16 bytes in length so it's most likely [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5). It is not SHA1 because the SHA1 hash value length would be 20 bytes.

Comment: It *could* be anything > 16 bytes including SHA1 or any of the SHA2 algorithms, because a larger hash can be truncated for various reasons. I would guess MD5 too.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like base-64 encoding.  That takes binary bytes and converts each series of 3 bytes into 4 characters, where each character can be one of 64 different characters defined by the base-64 encoding.  64 = 6 bits.  6 bits * 4 characters = 24 bits.  24 bits / 8 bits/byte = 3 bytes.  This looks like base 64 because it ends with "==".  I think the "=" character is used to pad out the end of the input when the characters and bytes do not align.

**Edit:** Based on the length of the code, it looks like it's encoded 16 bytes worth of data (128 bits).  It could be some kind of 128-bit hash or encryption key.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MD5 or SHA1, and then encoded the binary result into Base64, which is probably the encoding used in your example.

Answer (score 1):

possibly MD5 or SHA but no one can be so sure about it !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like base64 encoding [Check here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and [here](http://ostermiller.org/calc/encode.html)